# Cats eat wild rabbits: Disease risk?

Tags: cats, diseases

My cats catch and eat wild rabbits (Ontario, Canada). Normally the rabbits are juvenile.

I remember hearing that rabbits can have diseases that’s are harmful if eaten by humans (presumably even when cooked).

That has me wondering, can raw rabbit meat contain diseases that are harmful to cats?

The cats are fully vaccinated, including rabies shots.

Comment: Do you know, if this are european rabbits or cotton tail ones?

Comment: I know this is not the thing you are asking, but it is actually hurtful to the wildlife if your cat can freely hunt. I support wandering cats wholeheartedly (mine is wanderer too), but at least he has bell that scares all birds and rodents and he doesn't live close to a thriving wildlife community.